# Try and give a grouped (by two variables) average, and if not possible give column average in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, try-catch, pandas-groupby, average

I am trying to group by **2** variables and use the grouped average to fill the missing values in a column. Then, if that doesn't work, I want to groupby **1** variable and give the grouped average to fill the missing values of the same column, and if that doesn't work, I want to give the **average of the whole column** to fill the missing values (without any grouping as this is my last resort).

In the dataset I have a lot of companies, and 5 different product types: `Laptops/Desktops/Monitors/Tables/MobilePhones`

[image]

For example, i want to attempt to groupby the `company_name` and the `pl_category`, and use the resulting grouped average of `pl_use_energy_demand_(yearly_tec)` column to fill in the missing values for Apple's Tablet's in `pl_use_energy_demand_(yearly_tec)` column that are nan. However, as you can see, when I `groupby` Apple and Tablets_IPAD, there's no data to give a double grouped average to fill the missing values, so i'd like to fill in the nan values with Apple's average, and if no data for the whole Apple company, i'd like to fill in Apple's nan with the entire column average. So the desired output will be to fill in the nan values of the `pl_use_energy_demand_(yearly_tec)` column, using the order explained above and displayed in the code below:

```
features_to_impute = [
        x for x in dat.columns if dat[x].dtypes != 'O' and dat[x].isnull().mean() > 0.3 and x.startswith('pl')
        ]

def impute_cols(df,var_to_group1,var_to_group2,var_to_impute):
     return df.groupby([var_to_group1,var_to_group2])[var_to_impute].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))

def impute_cols_2(df,var_to_group_1,var_to_impute):
    return df.groupby([var_to_group_1])[var_to_impute].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))

for v in dat[features_to_impute]:
    try:
        dat[v+'imp'] = impute_cols(dat,'company_name','pl_category',v) 
    except:
        TypeError
    try:    
       dat[v+'imp'] = impute_cols_2(dat,'company_name',v) 
    except:
         dat[v+'_imp'] = dat[v].fillna(dat[v].mean())
```

The above code even though it does not give an error, **it returns the new '_imp' columns full of NaN's**.

Any suggestions on how to get what I need? Thanking you in advance.

The reason I use the

```
except:
    TypeError
```

is that sometimes when the dataframe is grouped, it doesn't have any data to give the grouped average, so it is my way of saying go and try the next part of the code.

Comment: could you add some data and desired output? Would make it easier to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Just did. Please let me know if the information above is still not enough.

Comment: Thanks, I like the way you explain your problem, that helps. As mentioned below, generating some data that explains the issue and can be copied makes helloing easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient way around this but because time is pressuring me I ended up doing something like this, which actually does exactly what I wanted it to do:

```
dict_list_1 = []
for v in dat[features_to_impute]:
    comp_mean = env.groupby('company')[v].mean().to_frame()
    dict_list_1.append(comp_mean)

comp_means = pd.concat(dict_list_1,axis=1,ignore_index=(False))    
comp_means.reset_index(inplace= True) 
   
def unique_id(df,col1,col2):
    return df[col1].astype(str) + "_" + df[col2].astype(str)

dat['company_ptype'] = unique_id(dat,'company_name','pl_category')    
env['company_ptype'] = unique_id(env,'company','category')
   
dict_list_2 = []
for x in dat[features_to_impute]:
    comp_ptype_mean = env.groupby(['company_ptype'])[x].mean().to_frame()
    dict_list_2.append(comp_ptype_mean)

comp_ptype_means = pd.concat(dict_list_2,axis=1,ignore_index=(False))    
comp_ptype_means.reset_index(inplace=True)

dict_list_3 = []
for i in dat[features_to_impute]:
    prod_type_mean = env.groupby(['category'])[i].mean().to_frame()
    dict_list_3.append(prod_type_mean)

prod_type_means = pd.concat(dict_list_3,axis=1,ignore_index=(False))    
prod_type_means.reset_index(inplace=True)

for x in dat[features_to_impute]:
    dat[x] = np.where(dat[x].isnull(),dat['company_ptype'].map(comp_ptype_means.set_index('company_ptype')[x]),dat[x]) # 1st step
    dat[x] = np.where(dat[x].isnull(),dat['pl_category'].map(prod_type_means.set_index('category')[x]),dat[x]) # 2nd step
    dat[x] = dat[x].fillna(dat[x].mean()) # 3rd  step
```

@Tito, if you have any suggestions on how to make this more efficient I am happy to hear them and use them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there I guess. The way you're creating the new column does not work. generate a list instead of a pd.Series in your function or in your fo loop should solve the issue.

```
features_to_impute = [
        x for x in dat.columns if dat[x].dtypes != 'O' and dat[x].isnull().mean() > 0.3 and x.startswith('pl')
        ]

def impute_cols(df,var_to_group1,var_to_group2,var_to_impute):
     return df.groupby([var_to_group1,var_to_group2])[var_to_impute].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))

def impute_cols_2(df,var_to_group_1,var_to_impute):
    return df.groupby([var_to_group_1])[var_to_impute].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x))

for v in dat[features_to_impute]:
    try:
        # create a list() here
        dat[v+'imp'] = list(impute_cols(dat,'company_name','pl_category',v)) 
    except:
        TypeError
    try: 
       # and here   
       dat[v+'imp'] = list(impute_cols_2(dat,'company_name',v)) 
    except:
       dat[v+'_imp'] = dat[v].fillna(dat[v].mean())
```

try this and tell me if it worked.
For the future try to create some pseudo data that can just be copied instead of a picture. That makes helping easier

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it doesn't give me what I need. The code basically ALWAYS gives the average of the whole column. So it fails to follow the order that i'd like it to follow. I believe that the last part of the try clause always overwrites the previous outputs (if any).

Comment: I checked again and I think the list() addition that you wanted me to add doesn't work in creating columns. So it's not that the 3 rd try clause is overriding them, it's that the first 2 try clauses don't work. @TiTo

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your problem then, sorry. Creating a list to insert the result as the column works for me. But I still don't get your data structure enough

Comment: Hi Tito. No unfortunately it doesn't - only the last part of the try clause code generates results. Try creating new columns for each try close and probably you'll see the same effect, columns are only created when this  `dat[v+'_imp'] = dat[v].fillna(dat[v].mean())` executes. Therefore, I changed massively the code and found another way to deal with the problem - which I am happy to share with you if you want.

Comment: sure! Would be interested to see how you solved it. Thanks

Comment: I added my answer below - If you have suggestions on how to improve (definitely it can be improved) feel free to share, will be appreciated.